# What is the write way to assign new values to a slice of dataset and return back the whole dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that I want to transform some columns and assign back the transformation into the existing dtaframe:

```
df.loc[:,df.columns != 'target'].pct_change(-1)
```

If I do:

```
df.loc[:,df.columns != 'target'] = df.loc[:,df.columns != 'target'].pct_change(-1)
```

I get a warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

What is the right to way to get back the transformed `df` ?  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `update`

```
df.update(df.loc[:,df.columns != 'target'].pct_change(-1))
```

Comment: It's very weird `pct_change(-1)` will make the last row `NaN` because it computes the percentage relative to it, however when we update the row goes back to the original value, that's clearly not a desirable thing. it should have stayed as `NaN`

Answer (score 1):

Filter out columns that have word target in them using df.filter

```
df[df.filter(regex='[^target]').columns]=df.loc[:,df.filter(regex='[^target]').columns].pct_change(-1)
```

Comment: regex and filter to a simple column assignment is overkill isn't it ?

Comment: Nope, you basically are telling it to use all other columns except the single column. It delivers the same thing `df.columns != 'target'` does. The alternative in both scenerios is to name all the other columns

Comment: Does the explanation help?

Answer (score 0):

After some research I think I found the best way to do this:

`df.loc[:,df.columns != 'target'] = df[df.columns[:-1]].pct_change(-1).to_numpy()`

According to pandas https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#basics the best way to apply a transform in place to a subset of columns is by using raw values, since my column was the last one I decided to not use `.loc` on the right side of the `=` sign but rather index out the last element of the list, that way I get no warnings.